# Is the given problem Undecidable?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

Does a TM M have a state that is visited no more than $K$ times when started on an empty tape ?

---

I tried to reduce it to halting problem, but didn't get the right way.

I want to know that is there any other method, it can be solved (except reduction) ?

Answer (score 4):

(NOTE: depending on your turing machine model, "accept" and "reject" may be considered their own state. If we do this, then the problem is decidable and trivial, so I will assumine these are special states that are not under consideration of the problem)

The typical solution for these kind of problems is to construct a TM $T_1$ that will simulate an arbitrary turing machine $T_2$ until it halts, where your property $P$ holds iff $T_2$ does end up halting, thus if we can decide $P$ we can decide halting for arbitrary TM $T_2$.

In these case, we will use the property "visits every state more than $K$ times".

It's easy to ensure that this property does not hold if $T_2$ never halts, just add some state "T_2_HALTED" that we visit after $T_2$ halts. We are simulating $T_2$ until it halts, so we never reach this state if $T_2$ never halts.

Now, we just need to ensure this property *does* hold for any $T_2$ that halts. In other words, we need some way to visit every state in our turing machine $K+1$ times.

(for simplicity I am going to assume that a TM model that can transition without moving the tape head left or right)

After we visit the "T_2_HALTED" state we need to visit every other state $K+1$ times. We do this by first placing an extra $K+1$ letters in our TM alphabet, $\alpha_0 ... \alpha_k$.

Then add to our transitions for every state other than "T_2_HALTED" that if it sees $\alpha_i$ on the tape for $i < k$, it will transition state to itself and write $\alpha_{i+1}$ on the tape without moving the tape head. If it sees $\alpha{k}$ on the tape, it will transition to another state according to some arbitrary total ordering on the state and write $\alpha_0$ on the tape (but make sure "T_2_HALTED" is the last state on this ordering).

Finally, the rule for "T_2_HALTED" is that if the value on the tape is not any $\alpha_i$, then it will transition to the first state in the ordering and write $\alpha_0$ on the tape, and if $\alpha_0$ to $\alpha_{k-1}$ is on the tape it will increment and transition to itself (like every other state), and if $\alpha_k$ is on the tape, $T_1$ halts.

So, the total effect is that by adding characters in our alphabet we can put a "side-algorithm" that lets us visit every state $K$ times, and we do this once $T_2$ halts. Since these are 'extra characters', we are assuming that these will never be written during our simulation of $T_2$, so we will never trigger this loop accidentally. Therefor, we visit every state $K$ times if and only if $T_2$ halts.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can do that. Take a machine you want to solve halting problem for, replace 'halt' with going to additional `halt` state and at the beginning cycle through all other states. Run your hypothetical check for this altered machine and $K=0$ and you've solved the halting problem (`true` means we won't reach `halt` state since we've visited all other states once in the beginning, `false` means we will get to `halt` which only happens in the end).